# Extending System.String for custom EditTemplate (Ajax) implementation

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-3

This is the following.

Normally, when i have a city, i'm using some javascript to autocomplete the cities as the user type.

Now i want it to make it automaticly, using the edittemplate. So i would change :

```
 Public String City{get;set;}
```

to

```
 Public City City {get;set;}
```

But i can't inherit the System.String class, so i would like the best alternative to do this.
I would create a new view of the City class and add javascript in my EditorTemplate, so i wouldn't ever have to add it anymore :) .

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am not following you in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that what you want is to use the `Html.EditorFor<City>()` method and its siblings, which doesn't work very well with simple types. You can make the `City` class implicitly cast to and from `System.String` and it should be indistinguishable from an actual `string`:

```
public class City
{
    private readonly string city;

    public City(string city)
    {
        if (city == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("city");

        this.city = city;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        City other = obj as City;
        return (other != null) && this.city.Equals(other.city);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return this.city.GetHashCode();
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return this.city;
    }

    public static implicit operator string(City city)
    {
        return city.city;
    }

    public static implicit operator City(string city)
    {
        return new City(city);
    }
}
```

This class can now be passed to methods that expect `System.String` and vice versa:

```
string city = new City("Washington");
City city = "Washington";
```

Comment: I already thought of implementing the toString method, but there won't be any better way i suppose.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I would not bother with a new type but use metadata on your models to change the editor. The `[UIHint("MyCityTemplate")]` attribute on the property will make EditorFor and DisplayFor use MyCityTemplate rather than the default editor template for string.

Comment: Excellent answer, which servers the porpose of my question. I have to admit, it ain't fair, but my literal question was to implement System.String, if i would have asked it differently (best way to change the different DisplayTemplate, ... I'd given you the best answer). Sorry, + 1 though!